# Hugo not processing template variable, go syntax in .md got ignored

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to show images from assets/images directory.
But I just realize that go code with syntax {{code}}
didn't get processed at all. It just print the code like a plain markdown content.

my config.yml about markup config just this

```
markup:
  defaultMarkdownHandler: goldmark
  highlight:
    noClasses: false
```

I should still using goldmark markdown default, but the go syntax got ignored.

[image: code inside {{code }} not processed]

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Go syntax, which usually goes into the layout files, with the markdown syntax, which goes into the content files.

You should have a look at shortcodes, that you can embed into Hugo content files.
https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/